# Android to BlackBerry App -> WebView is distorted

Tags: blackberry, android-webview, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

Converted an application using Android WebView as a wrapper for a Mobi site, this weird issue has occurred:

[image: Bug Issue]

[image: Google Apps Mobile]

[image: Google Mobile]

The app can scroll, only after rotating the view does it correct and still then it is only some of the time, additionally the issue can be presented when rotation is done if there was no issue before.

Tested Operating System:
Simulator
BB10.2.0X.1803 -> BB10.2.1.1925 (Occurs in all builds between)

BlackBerry Devices:

Z10 and Z30 running 1925.

I can provide more images if required.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is WebView the only thing in your app?

Comment: No, there are other activities, they are native Android and they work perfectly. I created this WebView app to show that any WebView was creating the issue.

Comment: Have found the solution, the webview needed to have hardware acceleration turned off.

Comment: Write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After awaiting a response from BlackBerry I have heard nothing so it is not confirmed that this will fix every issue with BlackBerry 10.2 devices and WebViews however it sure has resolved my issue.

The WebView appears to render incorrectly due to hardware acceleration being enabled on Android to BlackBerry applications, the solution to this problem is to disable hardware acceleration in one of two places.

```
if (Build.BRAND.equals(BLACK_BERRY)) 
{
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
}
```

Assuming that you have a WebView that is defined as webView, else deactivating the setting in the Android manifest for the entire application is also a feasible solution.

```
    <application 
       android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

This either one of these should solve the issue with the WebView.

Comment: As an update, you now need to for the latest version on the webView set it to software acceleration.